# jQuery.post is not sending data to the specified URL

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have a mobile application and I have a lot of data that I am putting in to a JSON object to store in localStorage. I need to get this data to PHP to process it. I have chosen to use jQuery.ajax to send the data as a JSON object to PHP. However, when I run the function, it gives a success message, but does not go to the url specified. I have a lot of PHP experience but this is my first JS intensive project.

Here is my JS code:

```
function sendToPHP() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: { "json" : ATRdataJSON},
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Data Sent!");
    },
  });
};
```

ATRdataJSON is a JSON object that has several JSON objects nested inside.

Comment: Not sure if it's normal, but you've written "ATR", shouldn't it be "ATTR" for Attributes ? Just a thought.

Comment: You should not have that dangling comma after success.

Comment: ATR is just part of the name of my JSON object

Comment: I removed that comma and it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The URL may not be pointing where you think it's pointing. Try:

```
function sendToPHP() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/email.php",
    data: { "json" : ATRdataJSON},
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Data Sent!");
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: I tested to make sure and it is pointing to the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid you cannot send the json object without stringifying it, it may be sent but as a string `[object]` try to check it first then you may make sure of the url is absolute to make sure it goes to the right controller.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, jQuery is making an internal stringification of the object, so it's probably not the problem.

Comment: @NisonMaël ok try to call the url with absolute url not relative.

Comment: I stringified the object just before this bit of code and I did test using the absolute URL, but to no avail.